# Export to eps in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, postscript, eps

I have a multiplot that I created with ggplot that I'm trying to export as an eps. I've tried multiple ways (postscript, setEPS) to do this but everything I get a blank eps file. I'm currently using this  code:

```
>postscript(postscript(file="~Desktop/REU/R/graphs.eps",horiz=TRUE,onefile=FALSE,width=8.5,height=11,paper=letter) 
all of the ggplot code
>multiplot(real1,real5, real2, real6, real3, real7, real4, real8, cols = 4) 
>dev.off()
```

I don't get errors, but after dev.off I get

```
null device
          1
```

Any suggestions on what to do would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Just add `setEPS()` before you run the `postscript`

Comment: An alternative approach would be to combine your graphs using `ggplotGrob()` and `grid.arrange()` functions in the `gridExtra` package, which would let you use `ggsave()`.

Comment: Getting `null.device` after dev.off() is not a sign of an error. It merely means that after the current device was closed that there was not another device ready to accept a new plot. Since you do not show any plotting code we have no idea what might be in the objects given to multiplot. Voting to close as an unclear problem statement.